# How to get rid of "Visibility for constructor is ignored" warning

Tags: solidity, truffle

In VS Code I get this warning in my contract constructor:

> Visibility for constructor is ignored. If you want the contract to be non-deployable, making it "abstract" is sufficient.

So I remove the visibility, leaving my constructor as

```
constructor()
```

Which removes the warning, but when running

```
$ truffle migrate --reset
```

I get this error

> SyntaxError: No visibility specified. Did you intend to add "public"?
> constructor() {
> ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines). Compilation failed. See above.

The migration runs fine with the warning

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

```
Truffle v5.2.5 (core: 5.2.5)
Node v12.16.3
```

Comment: constructor() public {  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like truffle uses a different solidity version than vs code. I'd recommend to specify one version in the code, 0.7 should be good enough.

```
pragma solidity 0.7.6;
```

The fix VS Code and Truffle so both use the same version.

Using wildcards only make sense if you are a framework developer.

Answer (score 5):

Encountered the same issue while moving from the old solidity version to the new one. Just had to remove the `public` keyword after the constructor.

```
constructor abc() public {
  // your code here.
}
```

to

```
constructor abc() {
  // your code here.
}
```